# Azure: Create Authorization token to access Azure Resource Management API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I want to get the health and other resource details of a particular Azure Account or Subscription using these API's 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resourcehealth/availabilitystatuses/listbysubscriptionid

When i do TryIt on the web page it works, but If i want to do it using say PostMan or programatically, how do i generate the Authorization key, I have seen docs to create Authorization Key using "App Registrations", but i dont have any WebApp here, All i want to do is get the details of a particular account or subscription using Azure provided API calls and using any AD user with proper roles for authentication.
This link provides some details but then i dont have a clientid here, since i dont have any webapp
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/azure/dn645543.aspx

Please let me know if anyone has tried doing this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to register an app in Azure AD.
This does not need to be an actual "Web app".
You are registering a service principal (you can think of it as a service account).
After registering the app (with type Web App/API), generate a Key for it.

Write down the Application Id (Client Id) and the key (Client Secret).
Then give the service principal access through the *Access Control (IAM)* section on the subscription/resource group/resource where you want to give the app access to.

You can then follow the instructions here to generate the access token: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/azure/dn645543.aspx.
Remember to use `https://management.azure.com/` as the `resource` since you are calling the ARM API.

Comment: Got it working. Thank you for mentioning the exact resource key to use, i got an error without it. Thanks

Comment: Is there any other way for me to access the Resource Management API or App Registrations is the only way for me to do it?

Comment: You need an app in Azure AD, there is no choice since the API is protected by Azure AD. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#register-your-client-application-with-azure-ad "Authentication is coordinated between the various actors by Azure AD, and provides your client with an access token as proof of the authentication."

Comment: Yeah, I actually just wrote a bit about it in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51283536/1658906

Comment: Though to do that you also need an app registered in AAD :)

Comment: Or use Azure AD PowerShell!

Comment: what if I provide my Azure Account UserID and Password, or create a user in Azure AD with necessary access and then provide this to the application can this be used to create the AzureAd entries programatically?

Comment: No, you always need an app. Even Azure PowerShell is registered as an app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174865/discussion-between-pharaoh-and-juunas).

Comment: I did the Authentication and Authorization using v2.0 app, since v2.0 does not have resource and has scope, what scope do i use to all the above ARM REST APIs.

Comment: I'm not sure if V2 supports that API yet

Comment: Hey are the ARM REST API free or are they charged?

Comment: It's free, no additional charges

Comment: I found his link which says its going to be charged https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/monitor/  is this relevant for ARM API as well?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/ is the API you want to call in here? If it is, then it seems there is some billing coming in December (I did not know this, thanks). If it isn't there, and is part of the standard ARM API, then I don't think there is any billing for that.

Comment: yes, there is some API from the list you have mentioned. Thanks